# Extracting a substring in Java using regex. How to include space characters

Tags: java, regex

I am extracting a string in JAVA using the following code:
The input is **(000) 000-0000111** and output should be **(000) 000-0000**

```
String text = "(000) 000-0000111";

 String pattern2 = "[(][0-9][0-9][0-9][)]\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";
 Pattern pattern_22 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
Matcher matcher_22 = pattern.matcher(text);

if(matcher_22.find()) {

    return matcher_22.group(0);
}
else
    return "NONE";
```

The output is coming as "NONE", it should be (000) 000-0000. Where am I going wrong. Can please someone point it out. TIA.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Once it's fixed, it returns the expected value. `pattern !== pattern_22`. The fact that you have such horribly named variables is probably an indication that your actual method is much too long, and uses several different patterns. Refactor it into smaller methods. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: No my goal is :

if input is (xxx) xxx-xxxxyyy then output should be (xxx) xxx-xxxx x= any integer

Answer (score 1):

From your comment :

> No my goal is : if input is (xxx) xxx-xxxxyyy then output should be
>   (xxx) xxx-xxxx x= any integer

If you want to replace the last three digits you can use :

```
phone = phone.replaceAll("\\d{3}$", "");
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eqYbqR/1)

---

> I don't want to replace it i want to extract it. There is a huge
>   difference !

In this case good tool is Pattern with Matcher, your regex can be `\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}` :

```
String text = "(000) 000-0000111";

String regex = "\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.group();
} else {
    return "NONE";
}
```

Comment: I dont want to replace it i want to extract it. There is a huge difference !

Comment: @hydra123 why don't you read the comments? Your code works fine, once you use the correct variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your pattern string with this :

```
[^1-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't compile. You need to modify it as follows

```
String text = "(000) 000-0000111";

String pattern2 = "[(][0-9][0-9][0-9][)]\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";
Pattern pattern_22 = Pattern.compile(pattern2);
Matcher matcher_22 = pattern_22.matcher(text);

if (matcher_22.find()) {
    return matcher_22.group(0);
} else {
    return "NONE";
}
```

This will output **(000) 000-0000** as you request in your question.

That said though, your current regex is quite verbose. You can use something much simpler, such as

```
\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4}
```

Noting that in java you have to escape backslashes, so within the context of your java code it will be

```
\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}\\-\\d{4}
```

Where `\d` represents a digit (0-9) and `{n}` represents a group of `n`, one after the other.

If, apart from this, you also want to know what was excluded from your input (as mentioned in a comment, you want to extract the trailing characters), you can use capture groups in your regex like for example

```
(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4})(.*)
```

Where the first capture group, `(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4})` will give you the pattern you want as output, and the second, `(.*)` will give you all the rest that came after. This also has to have escaped backslashes if used in Java.

With

```
pattern2 = "(\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}\\-\\d{4})(.*)";
```

You would have

```
String valid = matcher_22.group(1);
String rest = matcher_22.group(2);
```

where `valid` is `(000) 000-0000` and `rest` is `111`.